# HOW TO DO OBJECT RELATIONAL MAPPING(ORM) FOR THIS QUERY?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to convert my sql query into python code by using flask-SQLAlchemy.
I am stuck at one query.
there are tables name **flights** and **passengers** where flight_id(passengers) is foreign key and id(flights) is Primary key.

My sql-query is:

```
SELECT * FROM flights JOIN
passengers ON flights.id=passengers.flight_id;
```

please help me converting it in python

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
db.session.query(flights,passengers).filter
(flights.id==passenger.flight_id).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your models look something like these (this is pure sqlalchemy, rather than flask-sqlalchemy):

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm


class Flight(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'flights'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(64))

    passengers = orm.relationship('Passenger', back_populates='flight')


class Passenger(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'passengers'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(64))
    flight_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('flights.id'))

    flight = orm.relationship('Flight', back_populates='passengers')
```

then this query:

```
session.query(Flight).join(Passenger)
```

will generate this SQL when executed:

```sql
SELECT flights.id AS flights_id, flights.name AS flights_name 
FROM flights JOIN passengers ON flights.id = passengers.flight_id
```

and will return all the flight objects which have at least one passenger.

By contrast, this query:

```
session.query(Flight, Passenger).filter(Flight.id == Passenger.flight_id)
```

generates this SQL:

```sql
SELECT flights.id AS flights_id, flights.name AS flights_name, passengers.id AS passengers_id, passengers.name AS passengers_name, passengers.flight_id AS passengers_flight_id 
FROM flights, passengers 
WHERE flights.id = passengers.flight_id
```

which returns a `(Flight, Passenger)` tuple for each passenger that has a flight.

See the Sqlalchemy ORM tutorial for [creating relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship) and [querying with joins](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins).